# How to fix the issue with pyttsx3 module in spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have installed pyttsx3 package in spyder.
When i want to run simple code :

```
import pyttsx3 as ptx
speaker = ptx.init()
speaker.say('Hello World')
speaker.runAndWait()
```

I got the following error:

```
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()

KeyError: None


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes

ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 121, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]

KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'comtypes.LP_POINTER(ISpeechRecoGrammar)'>), 0)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ijeet\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    speaker = ptx.init()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = comtypes.client.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
    mod = GetModule(tlib)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 110, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 184, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 24, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 2170, in <module>
    ( ['in'], BSTR, 'AdaptationString' )),

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 329, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 698, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):



TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

How to fix this problem?
I am kind of beginner in spyder and python.

Whenever i am running this script in jupyter notebook, it is running successfully.
I have previously installed pip package directly from cmd. After spyder installation, i had to install within it the same package. THOUGH other simple python code run successfully but not this one.

Comment: I can run your code snippet without any issues in Spyder - so this might be related to how you install `pyttsx3`. Since you seem to run Spyder from Anaconda, you should probably use that to install modules as well.

Comment: I am not sure about one thing. Should the code and package be in same folder? It's still not working after reinstall packages.